# Isometry in Riesz's representation theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, riesz-representation-theorem

Riesz's representation theorem states that if $H$ is a Hilbert space and $H^*$ its dual space, then the map $\Phi$ which maps $x\in H$ to $x^*\in H^*, x^*y:=\langle x, y\rangle \,\forall\,y\in H$ is an antilinear isometric isomorphism. The fact that it is isometric is supposed to be trivial, and is presented as "manifestly true" in all proofs I could find, but the only thing I can tell is that by the Cauchy Schwartz inequality

$$||\Phi(x)||=\sup\left\{|\langle x, y\rangle|, ||y||\leq 1\right\}\leq\sup\left\{||x||\,||y||, ||y||\leq 1\right\}=||x|| $$

But why do we have equality?

Comment: Actually $x^*y=\langle y,x\rangle$. Your version of $x*$ is not quite linear...

Comment: It depends on the convention. I'm studying functional analysis for physics, the preferred convention in physics is that the scalar product is linear in the second argument and antilinear in the first, so that's how it's done where I read the theorem (it's more convenient for bra-ket notation I guess). That being said you're right that this is a mathematics oriented site and I should have adapted the convention to the standard one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $\|\Phi(x)\|\geq\left|\left<x,\dfrac{x}{\|x\|}\right>\right|=\dfrac{\|x\|^{2}}{\|x\|}=\|x\|$ for nonzero $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that 
$$\|\Phi(x)\| \ge \frac{|\Phi(x)(x)|}{\|x\|} = \frac{\langle x, x \rangle}{\|x\|} = \frac{\|x\|^2}{\|x\|} = \|x\| $$